# How can I call a method of type async Task<IHttpActionResult> from another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, azure

I have a **C#** Azure application where I have two websites in my solution. One is an outward facing website that a user hits, and the other is an API that the website hits to create users, etc.

Inside the second project (the API project), I've build a `Register` method with the code:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }

     IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);
     IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

     if (errorResult != null) {
         return errorResult;
     }
     return Ok();
}
```

This works great when calling this through a URL, and it works great when I call it via javascript in the website project.

However, I would like to now call this method from the server side of the website project, yet when I use the code:

```
SecondProject.API.Controllers.AccountController UserApiController = new SecondProject.API.Controllers.AccountController();
UserApiController.Register(UserApiModel);
```

visual studio warns me I should use `await`.

So if I add:

```
await UserApiController.Register(UserApiModel);
```

visual studio tells me the `await` operator can only be used in an async method.

**How can I call my `Register` method inside `SecondProject.API` from my first project on via server code????**

Comment: VS is guiding you towards the correct usage. Methods that return `Task<T>` should be `await`ed. To use `await`, the calling method must be `async`. Nothing unusual there, and I think the VS messages are pretty clear. Note that `async` will "grow" through the codebase; this is perfectly natural and should be embraced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the calling method as `async`.

[Official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/hh191443.aspx)

```
public async Task CallingMethod()
{
    //...
    SecondProject.API.Controllers.AccountController UserApiController = new SecondProject.API.Controllers.AccountController();
    await UserApiController.Register(UserApiModel);
    //...
}
```

EDIT:

In saying that, you should not be creating controller and calling methods in code. You should be using the repository, as you do in your controller method.

```
public async Task CallingMethod()
{
    //...
    IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);
    //Do something with the result
    //...
}
```